# What is efficient way to make aggregate million of records on remote server oracle data

Tags: sql, oracle

What is efficient way to make aggregate million of records on remote server oracle data.
Like

```
Select a, b, c, d, e, f, SUM(g), count(h), Avg(i)
From ABC
Group BY a, b, c, d, e, f
```

i don't want to use this method as it is looking very expensive.

please give me solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get why it looks very expensive. Databases are optimized to do aggregates on group by queries. So you better do this at database level.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/aggreg.htm try to read this document from oracle, it really help me a lot, understanding Aggregation.

Comment: There is no version of any query like this that would not "look" expensive on millions of rows.  There may be optimizations, but there is not enough information here to help out.

Comment: i found a function Cube in Oracle Pratik Reply Worked.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the query you want to run, you don't have much choice.

You could speed up the query using an index on `ABC(a, b, c, d, e, f, h, g, h, i)`.

This is a *covering* index for the query, so only the index needs to be used to evaluate the query.